# Transloco Unresolved pipe transloco

Tags: angular, transloco

I have an Angular 16 project, and I've installed Transloco, but when I try to use it in the HTML, I get the following error:

[image]

**Unresolved pipe transloco.**

When I start the Angular project, I can see that the translations are executed correctly.

How can I eliminate the error that the IDE is showing in the HTML file?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to import TranslocoModule, or TransolocoPipe from '@ngneat/transloco';

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but it's not working.